# Tabular into a .png when compile TeX document?

Tags: tables, compiling, tabularx

Do some of you know, whether it is possible or not to make a tabular into a .png when compile into a pdf TeX document?

Best,

Comment: You can use the `standalone` class, which will generate a cropped pdf with just the table that can be (automaticalyy) converted into a `png`. This would be the simplest, though manual solution.

Comment: If I may ask, why a tabular as PNG?

Comment: So you want a pdf file, but with a raster version of a table embedded?